Is this connection of (increasingly exclusive) integer partitions to the the Euler-Mascheroni constant useful?
$\mathbf{SETUP}$
From this previous question, I quote Cauchy's formula for the number of all possible cycle types
\begin{align}
    N_{\lambda} =
    \frac{n!}
    {1^{\alpha_1} 2^{\alpha_2} ... n^{\alpha_n} \times \alpha_1! \alpha_2! ... \alpha_n!}
    =
    \frac{n!}{\Lambda_\lambda}
\end{align}
and in this other previous question asked about why the remarkable result exists: that this sum tends to the exponential number raised to the inverse power of the $k$th harmonic number:
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{E}_k
    \equiv 
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{\lambda \in P_{n,k}}
    \frac{1}{\Lambda_\lambda}
    = e^{-H_k}
\end{align}
where the sum is over all the partitions of $n$ using integers strictly $> k$, $P_{n,k}$.
$\mathbf{RESULT?}$
Thus we can write the harmonic number as the logarithm of this limit:
\begin{align}
    H_k = -\ln \mathcal{E}_k
\end{align}
which clarifies the connection to the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma = 0.57721...$ from one of its definitions as
\begin{align}
    \gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(H_n - \ln n)
\end{align}
which, when written with an error term is:
\begin{align}
    H_n & = \ln n + \gamma + \epsilon
\end{align}
with the error being:
\begin{align}
    \epsilon = \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^2} + \frac{1}{120n^4} - \delta
\end{align}
with its final bound somewhere $0 < \delta < \frac{1}{252n^6}$, all according to the Wikipedia page.
Thus we can write:
\begin{align}
    \gamma + \epsilon & = H_n - \ln n
    \\
    \gamma + \epsilon & = -\ln \mathcal{E}_k - \ln n
    \\
    \gamma + \epsilon & = -\ln(\mathcal{E}_k n)
\end{align}
$\mathbf{QUESTION}$
Is this result relationship interesting or useful in any way? What explains this deep connection of partitions to Euler-Mascheroni?
The Arratia and Tavaré paper
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-20/issue-3/The-Cycle-Structure-of-Random-Permutations/10.1214/aop/1176989707.full
explains similar links in its section 5.2 (page 1586), but doesn't take it further, nor am I familiar enough with its notation to really understand what it's trying to say.


Consult Wilf's generatingfunctionology page 177, section 5.3.

@MarkoRiedel Thank you!! Example 5.7 ("Permutations with no small cycles") (page 191 of 3rd edition) is almost exactly my other question. Although I think I will need to read the entire book for a fuller understanding...
